# Weird question, but how do I make a python script to check if python is installed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Before you get confused, I am going to compile it with the auto-py-to-exe module after, its just the source code is in python. How do I do this?

Comment: "Is X installed?" is something best handled by your package manager, not your script.

Comment: you can use `cx_Freeze` to run a stand alone script (.py into an .exe) without python installed.

Comment: This almost sounds like a case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you provide some more context?

Answer (score 3):

If Python is not installed you wouldn't even be able to run a script to check if it's installed.

Comment: I said, I am going to compile it after making it. After compilation, it will not use python to run.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there isn't from inside the Python script. Because the interpreter isn't installed, so it'll never be able to understand HOW to execute the script at all.

You'll have to check outside in whatever is initiating the Python script and the compilation (bash script?) and do it there.

Comment: I am going to compile it after making it, so it does not need python to run. I said this in the body.